# Resignation - Is it fair for an employer to delay communicating about me leaving my company?

Tags: communication, resignation, morale

I've been with my company for 15 years and have just resigned b/c I'm moving to another city. I provided them with two months notice. My employer wants to delay announcing my departure to staff by three weeks b/c there has been a recent number of departures and they are concerned about the optics (from a board of directors and staff perspective) of another long-term employee leaving. I think their hope is that by delaying my resignation announcement they will have more of a buffer between staff departure announcements and compartmentalize the damage control required. My question is - is it fair for them to ask me to wait to announce my leaving? I have a team that I will need to train and a number of projects to tie up and not being able to start that process puts considerable pressure on me and the staff that will take on my work.

Comment: When you say they are delaying the announcement, do you mean that they are delaying a public announcement made to the whole company, or do they not want you talking about it at all?

Comment: The question is wrong. It does not matter if it is "fair" to you. Inform your boss about your concerns about the time left, tell him that you see possible damage to the company. Offer them to transfer some of the work earlier (under some pretext, or with the explanation that the boss decided).

Comment: The dupe is about why mgmt. do this, but this asker clearly knows why mgmt. do this - it's in the question!

Answer (score 7):

Your employer is presumably aware of the challenges that delaying announcement will cause. (If they aren't, you should communicate those.)

If they have evaluated the pros and cons of this decision and decided that they prefer you to delay announcement, then that is their decision.

Answer (score 5):

Sure it is. It's their company, they get to decide what information should be spread to their employees or not. They have determined that the benefits of you postponing your announcement outweigh the risks of you delaying your knowledge transfer. You might disagree, and you can feel free to tell your manager so, but it isn't your call to make.

I understand that will make it harder when you do get to start transferring your knowledge. You won't have as much time to do it, which means something might get left out, or your team will still have questions. Quite frankly, it isn't your problem. In 2 months you will be working somewhere else, and whatever problems arise in your wake will be for someone else to deal with. That's the decision your manager is making, so let them deal with it.

There is nothing stopping you from writing things down so you are ready to hand it over when you do announce your departure. And then when you do, do the best you can to train your people for what they need to know. Until you actually leave, you still work for them, so do the best job you can for them while you are still there. After that, they get to bear the consequences, not you. There is nothing unfair about that.